# How to writing rational at circle?

Tags: java, switch-statement, do-while

This program is a menu.(Please no quastion why this name)

```
    /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package menü.rendszer;
import java.util.Scanner;
/**
 *
 * @author Apa---2016
 */
public class MenüRendszer{

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
public static void main(String[] args){
Scanner beolv;
beolv=new Scanner(System.in);
boolean y=false;
do{
System.out.println("Válassz egy síkidomot!(Choose one plane figure!)");
System.out.println("(1)Téglalap(Retangle)");
System.out.println("(2)Kör(Circle)");
System.out.println("(3)Háromszög(Triangle)");
System.out.println("(4)Rombusz(Rhombus)");
System.out.print("Számkód:(Number code");
int x=0;
x=beolv.nextInt();
switch(x){
case 1:
    System.out.println("A kiválasztott síkidom:Téglalap(The choosed plane figure:Retangle)");
    int a=0;
    System.out.print("a=");
    a=beolv.nextInt();
    int b=0;
    System.out.print("b=");
    b=beolv.nextInt();
    int K=0;
    K=2*(a+b);
    int T=0;
    T=a*b;
    System.out.println("Kerülete(Perimeter):"+K);
    System.out.println("Területe(Area):"+T);
    System.out.println();
    break;
case 2:
    System.out.println("A kiválasztott síkidom:Kör(The choosed plane figure:Circle)");
    int R=0;
    System.out.print("R=");
    R=beolv.nextInt();
    K=0;
    T=0;
    K=(int)(2*R*3.14);
    T=(int)(R*R*3.14);
    System.out.println("Kerülete(Perimeter):"+K);
    System.out.println("Területe(Area):"+T);
    System.out.println();
    break;
case 3:
    System.out.println("A kiválasztott síkidom:(Derékszögű)Háromszög(The choosed plane figure:(Right)Triangle)");
    K=0;
    T=0;
    System.out.print("a=");
    a=beolv.nextInt();
    System.out.print("b=");
    b=beolv.nextInt();
    int c=0;
    c=(int) Math.sqrt(a*a+b*b);
    K=a+b+c;
    T=a*b/2;
    System.out.println("Kerülete(Perimeter):"+K);
    System.out.println("Területe(Area):"+T);
    System.out.println();
    break;
case 4:
    System.out.println("A kiválasztott síkidom:Rombusz(The choosed plane figure:Rhombus)");
    K=0;
    T=0;    
    int e=0;
    int f=0;
    System.out.print("e=");
    e=beolv.nextInt();
    System.out.print("f=");
    f=beolv.nextInt();
    K=e*e+f*f/4;
    T=e*f/2;
    System.out.println("Kerülete(Perimeter):"+K);
    System.out.println("Területe(Area):"+T);
    System.out.println();
    break;
default:y=false;break;
}
}
while(!y);
}
}
```

Can you see the circle? i tested, and for example the R=10 The original preimeter=62.8, but the output just 62. How to rational number?
Second question. How to leave switch with default? (I hope you understand, because i can't perfect speak English.)(I am Hungary.)

Comment: You are casting it to an int: `K=(int)(2*R*3.14);`. `K` would have to be type `float` or `double` (i.e.: `float K;` or `double K;`), and no casting necessary. Also, you should declare K before the `switch`.

Comment: `double K; K=(double)2*R*3.14;`.

Comment: @TamásFekete Ahol int típust használsz azt cseréld le double-ra. Ékezetes betűket pedig nem szokás fájl és csomagnevekbe rakni :)

Comment: Red underline.
Pirosan aláhuzza.

Comment: Az egész sort.
Full line.

Comment: Ha külön létrehozom a double-t, akkor azt húzza alá, de a szorzást nem.
If i make the new line (double K;), then underline the new, but the under not.

Comment: @TamásFekete Az a probléma, hogy a K és a T változód int. Írd át őket is double-ra.

Comment: @TamásFekete És cseréld le az összes változód double-ra. Egy double nagyobb és pontosabb mint egy Integer

Comment: Ja hogy az elején?

Comment: @TamásFekete Igen, mindenhol. Az 1-es caseben az a, b, K és T változót, case 2-ben az R-t, 3-ban a c-t, és az utolsóban az e-t és az f-et.

Comment: Megvan! Köszi a segítséget! :) Thank you for the help! :)
Már csak az  kéne hogy hogyan lépjek ki a switchből és fejezze be a ciklust? Mert most létre kellett hoznom egy booleant.

Comment: @TamásFekete A switch magától kilép, a hiba az, hogy az egész switchet egy loopba tetted, ami mindig igaz, mivel az y értékét sehol nem állítod true-ra.

Comment: Akkor kitörlöm az y-t de helyette mikéne?

Comment: Ne töröld ki az y-t, csak állítsd true-ra amikor kiszámolsz valamit. Válaszba megadom a kódot a módosításaimmal

Comment: Alapból az a feladat hogy addig ismételje az egész switchet, amíg a felhasználó ki nem szeretne lépni. Ha kiszeretne, akkor használja a defaultot. Csak nem tudom hogy.

Answer (score 0):

A hibád az volt, hogy az `y`-t a program elején hamisra állítottad, és a `default`-ban is. Ha az elején igazzal kezdesz, és addig ismételsz amíg `y` igaz, akkor jól fog működni.

Your problem was that you initialised `y` to false, and the `default` sets it to false as well. If you start with true, and loop while y is true, it will work fine.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner beolv;
    beolv = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean y = true;
    do {
        System.out.println("Válassz egy síkidomot!");
        System.out.println("(1) Téglalap");
        System.out.println("(2) Kör");
        System.out.println("(3) Háromszög");
        System.out.println("(4) Rombusz");
        System.out.print("Számkód: ");
        int x;
        x = beolv.nextInt();
        switch (x) {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("A kiválasztott síkidom: Téglalap");
                double a;
                System.out.print("a=");
                a = beolv.nextInt();
                double b;
                System.out.print("b=");
                b = beolv.nextInt();
                double K;
                K = 2 * (a + b);
                double T;
                T = a * b;
                System.out.println("Kerülete(Perimeter):" + K);
                System.out.println("Területe(Area):" + T);
                System.out.println();
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("A kiválasztott síkidom: Kör");
                double R;
                System.out.print("R=");
                R = beolv.nextInt();
                K = (2 * R * 3.14);
                T = (R * R * 3.14);
                System.out.println("Kerülete:" + K);
                System.out.println("Területe:" + T);
                System.out.println();
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.println("A kiválasztott síkidom: (Derékszögű) Háromszög");
                System.out.print("a=");
                a = beolv.nextInt();
                System.out.print("b=");
                b = beolv.nextInt();
                double c;
                c = Math.sqrt(a * a + b * b);
                K = a + b + c;
                T = a * b / 2;
                System.out.println("Kerülete:" + K);
                System.out.println("Területe:" + T);
                System.out.println();
                break;
            case 4:
                System.out.println("A kiválasztott síkidom: Rombusz");
                double e;
                double f;
                System.out.print("e=");
                e = beolv.nextInt();
                System.out.print("f=");
                f = beolv.nextInt();
                K = e * e + f * f / 4;
                T = e * f / 2;
                System.out.println("Kerülete:" + K);
                System.out.println("Területe:" + T);
                System.out.println();
                break;
            default:
                y = false;
                break;
        }
    }
    while (y); // Addig ismételje amíg y igazra van állítva, a default hamisra rakja és kilép a program.
}
```

Comment: Szóval ha nem az 1 és 4 között adok meg számot, akkor vége a programnak?

Comment: @TamásFekete Igen

Comment: Működik. Hát nagyon szépen köszönöm a segítséget. :) Nem gondoltam volna hogy egyből válaszolni fog egy magyar ember.

Comment: @TamásFekete Sokkal kellemesebb egy magyar embernek segíteni egy ilyen nagy oldalon! Örülök, hogy működik.

Comment: Nagy igazság. :)